# Meteor : One database per tenant in multi-tenancy app

Tags: meteor

Most of the older blogs/posts suggest to use tenant_id in every entry in a collection. And use tenant_id in every query to isolate tenants in a Meteor app.

But, is it now possible to have one MongoDB database per tenant in a multi tenant app and make Meteor switch between those databases depending on tenant_id/subdomain? Or adding tenant_id to every entry is the only way to implement multi-tenancy in Meteor?

Comment: Why do you want one database per tenant?

Comment: @merlinpatt In some domains like banking and health care having a clients data intermixed in one database can be dangerous, just once you forget to filter by tenant id and customer a see customer b's data.  Segregating at the database level also allows you to more easily move customers data, for example, customer paying at an entry tier in a saas may all be on a small db server while those paying for a premium tier may be upgraded to a larger db server.  Moving databases between servers is easier a lot easier then importing and exporting data based on Ids between two databases.

Comment: I can agree with moving data might be slightly easier and the tiering. However, not intermixing because you might forget to filter is not much of a reason. You could just as easily mess up your code in such a way that two databases are accessed instead of one. As such, I don't think that separating clients into separate DBs adds that much security or ease of operations.

Comment: I am looking for same, let me know if you found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but undocumented - use at your own risk:

```
var d = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("<mongo url>");
C = new Mongo.Collection("<collection name>", { _driver: d });
```

Comment: Please explain the given example, what's `C` and is it intentionally global?